# Q: Ansible. Report failures when using ignore_errors

Tags: testing, ansible

Is there a way to allow failures to increment the fail count when using ignore_errors?

Edit: since it may be unclear for some, will someone let me know how to do this?

Comment: Yes, there is a way to allow failures to increment the fail count when using ignore_errors.

Comment: Would you mind telling me how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it is impossible without modifying Ansible code.

Failure count is increased by [`stats.increment('failures', ...` method](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/stable-2.5/lib/ansible/plugins/strategy/__init__.py#L492) which is executed inside the [`if not ignore_errors:`](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/stable-2.5/lib/ansible/plugins/strategy/__init__.py#L479) condition.

Otherwise (i.e., when `ingore_errors: true`) an OK-counter is increased:
 [`stats.increment('ok', ...`](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/stable-2.5/lib/ansible/plugins/strategy/__init__.py#L511).

Comment: I will trying this method Monday. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using some unix flavor

```
ansible-playbook pb.yml | tee >(grep -c FAILED)
```

this should print the number of failures